# Constant variable has to be used on each API call

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5

i have 2 values string abc=workkey and string xyz=terminalid which will be obtained by first API[webmethod],thees values has to be used in the next 4 api calls,ones this set is completed , i need to clear the abc and xyz .
For the next set of api call[[webmethod] i will get a new abc and xyz from the first API.
how can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you write the code of calling APIs? Can you share that code here? Constant values are passed from the client to the API or from the API to the client?

Comment: reassign it that's all

Comment: string xyz is generated from client  end which should be constant for the 4 api communication, sring xyz is obtained from server which is decrypted at client end and need to use in 4 api call,i need that whether i can implement by using readonly concept or any suggestion on this available?

Comment: i have 2 application combination here,one is windows application and the webservice hosted in IIS,my code us written in webservice to call the API,i need the 2 strings to be stored locally in webservice when my windows appliction is processing the response